# Pager does not scroll

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I cannot understand why the pager does not scroll when I changed isInputMode inView model. In debugger i see that the target page is selected properly, however, pager remains on page 1

```
            val targetPage = if (state.isInEnputMode) 1 else 0
            var key by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0, pageCount = { 2 })

            LaunchedEffect(key1 = key) {
                launch {
                    delay(2000)
                    with(pagerState) {
                        animateScrollToPage(page = targetPage) //Broken
                        key = !key
                    }
                }
            }
            
            HorizontalPager(
                state = pagerState,
                
                userScrollEnabled = false,
            ) { page ->
                if (page == 0) {
                  Page1()


                  
                } else {
                  Page2()
                }
```

Comment: you should add code that shows the type of state and how you update the state in the viewModel. I don't see anything wrong with this code that would cause it not to work.